# Add a second function to this jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

The following jQuery function filters my table columns by letter. There is an `<a>` for each letter. I'm not sure how to add another function though to filter column 1 using a different dropdown on the html side.

**JavaScript:**

```
function fil(rexp)
{
    $('#tablestyle').dataTable().fnFilter(rexp, 0, true, false);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div style="float:left;" class="sortalpha">
    <a href="javascript:fil('');">ALL</a>
    | <a href="javascript:fil2('^a');">A</a>
    | <a href="javascript:fil('^b');">B</a>
    <!-- [...] -->
    | <a href="javascript:fil('^z');">Z</a>
</div>
```

What I have tried to do is copy the top part and change `fil` to `fil2` then copy the HTML part and change those to `fil2`. Is that the correct way?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Just to give everyone a bit more info, I am using datatables {www.datatables.net} which is a jquery script that presents tables in a nice looking ui with various differnt functions to it like search, filter records per page etc.
I have implemented this mod that someone has listed here >> http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/6641/filtering-with-first-letter/p1

It works fine and when I select each letter it filters column 0 using whatever letter I have clicked on. What I am trying to do is have two different filters, one to filter column 0 which is the name of the person, and also another filter that does exaclty the same thing, but for column 1 which is business name, I just wasnt sure how to add the same piece of code twice?.

Comment: Can you try to rephrase you question, and show some HTML of the rest of the side, especially the dropdown. I read this post three times but it isn't clear to me.

Comment: +1 @saratis this is very unclear. what are you trying to achieve where is the html? etc

Comment: And make sure to return false on the click event of the link

Comment: actually I think I understand what you are trying to achieve - but do you want to refer to the same #tablestyle table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know your context, but I would suggest you try using **event handlers** instead of JavaScript URLs.

So instead of this:

```
<a href="javascript:fil('');">ALL</a>
```

You could do this:

```
$('.sortalpha a').on('click', function() {
    fil('');
});
```

Of course, this would make *all* links filter on `''`. To fix that, you could get the text from the `<a>` that was clicked and use that to call `fil()`, like so:

```
function fil(rexp) {
    if (rexp.length > 0) {
        rexp = '^' + rexp;
    } 
    //$('#tablestyle').dataTable().fnFilter(rexp, 0, true, false);
    alert('Filter on: "' + rexp + '"');
}

$('.sortalpha a').on('click', function(event) {

    var letter = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

    if (letter === 'all') {
        fil('');
    } else {
        fil(letter);
    }
});
```

Here's a **working example: http://jsfiddle.net/uzGat/2/**

**Edit:** I updated the answer to account for capital letter and the `^` in the regular expressions.

Comment: Hi, how would this work with two different filter though ?, as I need to filter column 0 on one filter and column 1 on the other.

Comment: Ah, so that's what you want to do... Have you taken a look at this? http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/regex.html The second argument to `fnFilter()` is the column index.

Answer (score 1):

if the plugin is well written, it must maintain chainbilty so you can do like:

```
function fil(rexp)
{
$('#tablestyle').dataTable().fnFilter(rexp, 0, true, false).fnFilter(rexp2, 0, true, false);
}
```

Comment: Hi, what would I need to put in the html for two different lists as the links are currently calling 'fil' in the url, so I cant put 'fil' in the url for the 2nd list too.